# Release lock of H2 database

Tags: locking, h2

I'm trying to use row-level locking in H2 database. Is there any way to get and release record-level locks in a single connection?

```
SELECT *
FROM "locks"
WHERE key = 'lock1'
FOR UPDATE;

SELECT *
FROM "locks"
WHERE key = 'lock2'
FOR UPDATE;
```

Now i want to relase **lock1**, but continue to hold **lock2**.
I've tried to insert "BEGIN TRANSACTION;" before lock2, but COMMIT release both locks.

**Addition:**
I'm going to use H2 like local cache for server database.
Goal is to implement cross program synchronization (java).
Data will not be synchronized 1:1, program will control what to store.
FileChannels does not work in Linux, sockets works fine, but i find them ugly solution.
Tasks:

1. Database synchronization with server; Only one program should execute synchronization.
2. Log writing; Program use 2 log files and switch from one to another. To prevent collision we should lock file for write time.
3. May be something else.

At this moment i see two ways

1. Create new connection each time and release after task execution. Connection establishing takes nearly 600ms.
2. Use temporary tables: CREATE AND DROP TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_lock1(). Takes 2ms. Problem: if there are 2 connections and 1st create temporary table and suddenly finish the work (e.g. some bug), table will still exist until 2nd program is working.

Answer (score 0):

I never tried it myself, theoretically you should be able to **insert** a record, **select it for update** and **release the lock by deleting** the record. H2 may not be used in *MVCC*-Mode otherwise the new record would not be seen by another connection.

I am not sure, what you want to achieve, this might probably not be the way to go, but the lock should be released and the other persist.

Answer (score 0):

In theory you should be able to use SAVEPOINT like so:

```
SELECT * FROM "locks" WHERE key = 'lock1' FOR UPDATE;
SAVEPOINT beforeLock2;
SELECT * FROM "locks" WHERE key = 'lock2' FOR UPDATE;
ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT beforeLock2;
```

In practice it doesn't work and the `lock2` row remains locked, might be a bug so I'm posting it in hope Thomas will see it.

From what you described I don't see any reason why you won't be able to use 2 connections one for `lock1` and another for `lock2`. You can use a connection pool and then the time it takes to create a connection won't be an issue.